# Am i properly handling this float variable?

Tags: java

I want to make sure that initializationg of the float variable resultd is correct. Since it is where the error lies.

```
static void caculateValues() {


    int a, b;
    int resulta, results, resultm;
    float resultd;
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter a:");
    a = sc.nextInt();
    System.out.print("Enter b:");
    b = sc.nextInt();
            {  

   //This is the only part I edited//

   resulta= a+b;
   results=a-b;
   resultm= a * b;
   resultd= a / b;

   //This is where I stopped editing//
    }    


    System.out.println("The result of adding is " + resulta);
    System.out.println("The result of subtracting is " + results);
    System.out.println("The result of multiplying is " + resultm);
    System.out.println("The result of dividing is " + resultd);


}
```

They claim my output should looks something like this:

```
(a = -50) (b = -20) 
The result of adding is -70
The result of subtracting is -30
The result of multiplying is 1000
The result of dividing is 2.5
```

But supposedly my input shows:

```
The result of adding is -70
The result of subtracting is -30
The result of multiplying is 1000
The result of dividing is 2.0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if `resultd` is a `float`, you are still dividing two `int`s:

```
a / b
```

In Java, division of 2 `int`s must be an `int`.  That is why `2.0` is showing up.  `-50 / -20` is `2`, not `2.5` in Java.  Only after the `2` is generated is it promoted to a `float` upon assignment to `resultd`.

Cast one of the variables to a `float` to force floating-point math from the start.

```
resultd = (float) a / b;
```

You could just as easily make `resultd` a `double` and cast `a` to a `double` instead.

Comment: Thanks, this solved my question. I tried making resultd a double instead, but when I did that, the code wouldn't process since it was on a java practice website. So they must have only wanted it the way they formatted it.